# Dual Boot - Boot Repair - Problems with Legacy vs UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair, grub-legacy

i am normally running Win7 Pro as the only OS on my Thinkpad T420s. Yesterday, i wanted to install ubuntu. I downloaded the ISO and made a bootable USB stick - on a Macbook via Balena Etcher.

After some Problems related to some BIOS settings and some random changes there (I wasnt aware of TPM, CSM, Legacy, UEFI and all the stuff i have learnt now) i have managed to install Ubuntu 20.10 as a secondary OS on the manually created now partition.

As i found out (not 100% sure), my Win7 is installed as BIOS, Ubuntu boots via UEFI.

But even if i change my BIOS settings to boot in BIOS-only (legacy), computer prompts, there is no bootable device/image. But i cannot boot Ubuntu and cannot boot from USB.

If i change the settings to EFI, i can start both - Ubuntu and USB. I read, that should be easily handled and solved with boot-repair. The automatic repair mode cannot help, because it detectes a win-legacy. It wants me to change the BIOS settings and do it again - which brings me to the first point and closed the circle, i need help to escape from.

Here is the Logfile of Boot Repair:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZxzyRG6H7X/

As we can see, the Win7-OS is untouched, everything is okay. And i hope, that the solution shouldnt be too complicated. But i havent found the right idea to tackle that.

Currently i am trying to make the USB bootable in legacy mode. And hope, that boot-repair then accompanies me through the automatic repair mode.

Thanks for reading and for any prompt help!

Victor.

Comment: Hello again, i made some progress (hopefully) and managed to do a legacy-bootable-usb-drive with ubuntu. i am in live-mode now, running boot-repair. i thought, i am pretty close now, but the automatic repair cannot finish, as "grub is stsill installed". i made all the terminal commands which should be done to remove. but it isnt. ahhh! and here is the pastebin: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bWDg4RvzFq/

Comment: You need to install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode that Windows is installed in, in your case BIOS, (ie Legacy). If Ubuntu is installed UEFI, GRUB will not boot Windows. I think you need to reinstall Ubuntu, not just change the bootloader.

Comment: Hello Cameron - Thanks.. havent tried that. i am giving it a try right now.

Comment: It worked.. it worked out pretty well! Thanks a lot! Lessons learnt: Doent mess with EFI and BIOS. The USB Flash Image Creator tool didnt asked me what boot mode i want. As far as i read, same with unetbootin. The automatically use UEFI. Thats a big problem! There is one tool, which makes bootable usb flash for both modes, BIOS and UEFI. its called the Startup Disk Creator. That helped me to make another ubuntu usb flash, which can load under strictly legacy mode only. and from that - thanks so cameron - i installed ubuntu again. and now, not sure of everything is fine, but i could boot win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows and Ubuntu Same Mode

You need to install Ubuntu in the same BIOS/UEFI mode that Windows is installed in, in your case BIOS, (ie Legacy).

If Ubuntu is installed UEFI, GRUB will not boot Windows. I think you need to reinstall Ubuntu, not just change the bootloader.

Comment: You have to move boot flag from ESP to Windows boot partition with it boot files. Windows has to have boot flag on primary NTFS partition with its boot files. Grub does not use boot flag, but UEFI also has to have boot flag on ESP - efi system partition. So UEFI install on Windows BIOS/MBR drive, moves boot flag to ESP and Windows will not boot. Only one boot flag per drive/device. Total reinstall of grub will work by uninstalling grub-efi-amd64 and installing grub-pc for BIOS boot.